# Sort by ACF option and also from current category - custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

With use of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin I created a select dropdown which contains 6 membership types. All of my 'listings' using this custom field are assigned one of the 6.

[image]

I have managed to get my listings to display in order of membership level, however it's not defining by category that your currently in. It's grabbing listings from every other category too.

```
<?php 
// args
 $args = array(
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_type' => 'directory_listings',
     'meta_key' => 'membership_type',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value',
     'taxonomy' => 'listing_category'
 );

// query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args )

?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ldl_get_template_part('listing', 'compact');
        ldl_get_featured_posts();
    }
    ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, I am using the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ldd-directory-lite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP_Query does not have a `taxonomy` parameter, you should use `tax_query` instead. More info in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'my-listing-category',
    ),
),
```

To grab the current taxonomy term dynamically (assuming you're on a `listing_category` taxonomy page):

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => get_queried_object_id(),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Ah ok yeah I see this now. As a test I set the 'terms' to 'associations' one of my categories. Works great, however how may I be able to grab the current category slug like this dynamically.